# Global is not defined in Nuxt 2.5 and higher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

My app used Nuxt 2.1, than I graduately updated it and till Nuxt 2.4 everything is ok, but from 2.5 and up production builds brake with `global is not defined` error.

Place of error is in `.nuxt/client.js@26`:

```
if (!global.fetch) { global.fetch = fetch }
```

I can't figure out how to fix this (need to define `global` as far as I understand) and no answers out there. As well as such bug reports, what is strange.

Dependencies list:

```js
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.7",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.4.2",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.4.2",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
        "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.0.1",
        "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.5.3",
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
        "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.3.0",
        "@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.2.0",
        "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.0.0",
        "@saeris/vue-spinners": "^1.0.8",
        "apexcharts": "^2.0.9",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "canvas": "^2.0.1",
        "deep-map": "^2.0.0",
        "deepmerge": "^3.3.0",
        "element-ui": "^2.4.7",
        "glob-all": "^3.1.0",
        "html-element-attributes": "^2.0.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.3",
        "lockr": "^0.8.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "nib": "^1.1.2",
        "nuxt": "^2.8.1",
        "nuxt-babel": "^1.0.1",
        "nuxt-i18n": "^5.12.7",
        "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "raw-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "rupture": "^0.7.1",
        "s-grid": "^1.2.1",
        "stylus": "^0.54.5",
        "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
        "underscore": "^1.9.1",
        "v-viewer": "^1.3.1",
        "vue-apexcharts": "^1.2.1",
        "vue-awesome": "^3.2.0",
        "vue-cookie-law": "^1.10.0",
        "vue-filter": "^0.2.5",
        "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.28",
        "vue-lodash": "^2.0.0",
        "vue-nl2br": "^0.1.1",
        "vue-scrollto": "^2.15.0",
        "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
        "vue-wysiwyg": "^1.7.2",
        "vue2-editor": "^2.6.6",
        "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.6",
        "vue2-transitions": "^0.2.3",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
        "@babel/node": "^7.5.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.5.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.5.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.0",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "deep-map-async": "^1.5.1",
        "electron": "2.0.0-beta.7",
        "electron-builder": "^20.8.1",
        "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.3",
        "es6-weak-map": "^2.0.3",
        "eslint": "^4.15.0",
        "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "google-translate-api": "^2.3.0",
        "tosource": "^1.0.0",
        "translatte": "^2.4.3",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
        "yargs": "^13.2.4"
      }
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you remove package-lock.json / yarn.lock before upgrade? I guess you've looked at the release [notes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/release-notes/#v2.5.0).

Comment: @Andrew1325 removed yarn.lock and cleared node_modules, updated nuxt to 2.5 - the same. dev build works, prod - no

Comment: what node version?

Comment: @Aldarund 10.12 but this is irrelevant as error is on client

Comment: babel/nuxt preset should be used. So i suggest to remove all your custom babel conf and deps and try with default. And if it work - you can customize babel https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#babel

Comment: @Aldarund thank you. viewed the docs, they say that default preset is is @nuxt/babel-preset-app. Specifiying it manually leads to `Unexpected token export` error and app not rendering at all:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/djkdi39391nzyev/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202019-07-16%2013.30.38.png?dl=0

setting build config too default babel: {babelrc: false} with plugins allows to work SSR, but client fails with error `Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'` :(

Comment: @Aldarund last error resolved when I removed packages from `build.transpile`, and with default babel config + plugins 
`
    babel: {
    babelrc: false,
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"
    ]
    },
`
app started... but with the same error `global is not defined` :(

Comment: well its hard to say without exact repro. Try also to remove lock file and deps and reinstall

Comment: @Aldarund I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059769/1114816

Comment: @Aldarund thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of investigation I've figured out that problem was in this config:

```
extend(config, {isDev, isClient, isServer}) {
  if (isClient) {
    config.target = process.env.BUILD_TARGET || 'electron-renderer';
  }
})
```

Have ho idea why it all worked prior 2.5 and broke after, but here is the case